# Trying to explain to first year students that $\det$Diag$(A,B)$ = $\det A \cdot \det B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m$ by $m$ matrix and $B$ an $r$ by $r$ matrix and let
Diag$(A,B)$ be a block diagonal matrix. It is an $(m+r)$ by $(m+r)$ matrix where the top left $m$ by $m$ corner is $A$, the bottom right $r$ by $r$ corner is $B$ and $0$ else where.

I am trying to explain to first year students that $\det$Diag$(A,B)$ = $\det A \cdot \det B$. I was wondering if someone could assist me with how I can explain to them in a clear manner (other than just giving an example or two)? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix} 
=
 \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & I_r
\end{bmatrix} 
 \begin{bmatrix}
I_m & 0\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\det \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & I_r
\end{bmatrix} 
\det \begin{bmatrix}
I_m & 0\\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix} = \det A \det B $$.

It should be easy to demonstrate that

$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix} = \det A  $$

based on the normal technique involving minors.

Comment: O this is a simple trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could prove this directly from the definition of determinant. Or using the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). This should be quite straightforward as the upper and lower off-diagonal blocks will now have zero contribution to the determinant.